# Change Windows 7 scrollbar colors

Tags: windows-7, scrollbar

Being legally blind in left eye, now right eye is blurry.  My Windows 7 scrollbars' grays "blend together" and are difficult to see.

How can I either change to two colors or to two contrasting grays?

Comment: Can you explain what "Sidebar" you are referring to? Maybe a screenshot? Windows 7 does not have a "Sidebar" (Windows Vista does though).

Comment: @Rain I think its about the `Scroll Bar`.

Comment: Yes, the Scroll Bar!

Comment: Have you tried high contrast themes available in Personalization?

Answer (score 2):

Windows includes high contrast themes for people with vision troubles...

In Windows 7 you can toggle High Contrast mode with <kbd>Left Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Print Screen</kbd>.

You can select and permanently enable a high contrast theme as well.  Just right-click a blank area of the Desktop and choose "Personalize".  Scroll down a bit and there should be a few different "Basic and High Contrast Themes" to choose from.

Comment: Bless you all!  I will "play" with them until I find something that works.  I also have Alzheimer's and get a bit confused.  I'll ask my son to help me:)